# Radio Button with images formatting

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to have three images across each line with a radio button underneath each. I am not too familiar with forms and I just cannot figure out why the images are rendering out this way. Anyone have any thoughts or any ideas at how to create this?

/jess/design.html

edit: figured out part of it... problem with the width on forms. still trying to figure out how to get the radio button underneath if anyone cant help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just put each radio button with its image inside a div with `width: 100%`, It should do the trick.

EDIT: No wait, that will put the radio on the right side of the image, try also adding 100% width to the image inside the wrapping div and setting the width of the wrapping div to the value you want for the number of column desired (50% for 2 columns)

Answer (score 0):

Nest the divs and apply the appropriate rules:

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SREMB/4/

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">

<div class="cell">
<img src="http://connorreaumond.com/jess/images/beads/grey.gif"><br>
<input type="radio" name="bead" value="grey" />
</div>

<div class="cell">
<img src="http://connorreaumond.com/jess/images/beads/ivory.gif"><br>
<input type="radio" name="bead" value="ivory" />
</div>

<div class="cell">
<img src="http://connorreaumond.com/jess/images/beads/mattsmoke.gif"><br>
<input type="radio" name="bead" value="mattsmoke" />
</div>
</div>

<br><br>


<div class="row">

<div class="cell">
<img src="http://connorreaumond.com/jess/images/beads/grey.gif"><br>
<input type="radio" name="bead" value="grey" />
</div>

<div class="cell">
<img src="http://connorreaumond.com/jess/images/beads/ivory.gif"><br>
<input type="radio" name="bead" value="ivory" />
</div>

<div class="cell">
<img src="http://connorreaumond.com/jess/images/beads/mattsmoke.gif"><br>
<input type="radio" name="bead" value="mattsmoke" />
</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="row">

<div class="cell">
<img src="http://connorreaumond.com/jess/images/beads/grey.gif"><br>
<input type="radio" name="bead" value="grey" />
</div>

<div class="cell">
<img src="http://connorreaumond.com/jess/images/beads/ivory.gif"><br>
<input type="radio" name="bead" value="ivory" />
</div>

<div class="cell">
<img src="http://connorreaumond.com/jess/images/beads/mattsmoke.gif"><br>
<input type="radio" name="bead" value="mattsmoke" />
</div>
</div>

<br><br>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

you can this one, http://jsfiddle.net/ayBeh/

I suggest you that ID should Use on time at same page, so please use .bead instead "#bead",
sorry to say BRO, I Saw your code, not much cleaner , there is lots of cleanup issues,
I think Your not familiar with HTML also, but anyways you tried best, keep it up, if want help contact me any time,